# Slim Framework returning response without 'return $response'

Tags: php, slim

I'm confused with how Slim is returning a response without `return $response` as per the documentation.

If I have the following code:

```
$app->get('/login', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $response = $this->view->render($response, "login.php");
    return $response;  
});
```

When I call `/login` through my browser it renders my `login.php` template, which is what I'd expect.

**But if I remove `return $response` it still works** which doesn't seem right?

```
$app->get('/login', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $response = $this->view->render($response, "login.php"); 
});
```

Both sets of code have the same output.

How is Slim showing the response if `$response` is *not* being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body is a `Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface` which is not immutable, when you append something to the body you normally do:

```
$body = $response->getBody();
$body->write($string);
$body->write($string2);
```

This changes the content of the stream but is still in the same `$response`-Object.

As the view renderer only appends to the body, there is no need to actually return the `$response`.