# SlimFramework php v3, withStatus(500) does not work

Tags: php, slim-3

I started learning PHP Slim-Framework v3. But I'm finding it difficult on few occasions.

Here is my code:

```
$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);
$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {
    $error = array('result' => false, 'message' => 'Bad Request', 'dev'=>'', 'data' => []);
    $response->withStatus(500)->getBody()->write(json_encode($error));
});
```

Now I want to respond with status 500 to the user when ever I have issues in service. But unfortunately this is not working. Though I'm getting a response, it is returning 200 status instead of 500.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

I tried looking into other issues but I did not find anything helping me out.

Comment: Aside (?): If the request is bad, 500 is the wrong response code; 400 is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I wasn't my service to return the different error code when URL does not match. Hence I read in SLIM document that withStatus(500) will do that. But not sure why this is not working.

Comment: @deceze - I hope you got what I was trying to say. I just want to change status using withStatus and this is not working

Comment: Not sure why that doesn't work, but this seems to:
return $response->withJson($error,500);

Comment: Also, don't forget to return your response.

Comment: After a few other tests, this does work:
return $response->withStatus(500)->write(json_encode($error));

I removed the getBody() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Response`-object is immutable, therefore it cannot be changed. The methods `with*()` do return a copy of the `Response`-object with the changed value.

```
$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {
    $error = array('result' => false, 'message' => 'Bad Request', 'dev'=>'', 'data' => []);
    $response->write(json_encode($error)); // helper method for ->getBody()->write($val)
    return $response->withStatus(500);
});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40191776/4244993) why you dont need to reassign the value on `write`.

You can also use `withJson` instead:

```
$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {
    $error = array('result' => false, 'message' => 'Bad Request', 'dev'=>'', 'data' => []);
    return $response->withJson($error, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I tried this before but seems like i was calling it wrong. :-)

Comment: hey i have the same problem but the difference is that i need to do it inside my custom class. how i write my reponse is $response -> getBody() -> write(json_encode($this -> parseObject(703, 'Missing Params!')));. I want to add response code instead but couldn't get it working with your answer, any idea ?