# Custom response code in custom class | Slim Framework 3

Tags: php, slim

Hey i've been trying slim for several days now i am able to make simple API like so

```
$app->get('/articles/getcategories', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
(new Category) -> getCategories($response);
});
```

one problem is when i want to send a custom response code to my end point from my class, in this case Category class it doesn't work, i was able to send a response using this method :

```
$response -> getBody() -> write(json_encode($this -> makeObject(704, 'Something went wrong!')));
```

But when i look at the documentation :

```
$newResponse = $response->withStatus(302);
$data = array('name' => 'Rob', 'age' => 40);
$newResponse = $oldResponse->withJson($data, 201);
```

or like this :

```
return $response->withStatus(xxx);
```

it doesnt work, this is my custom class

```
 public function getCategories($response){

    $dbconn = (new db())->connect();
        //start db connection
    try {
        $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT category_id, category_name, category_description, category_type FROM article_category");

        $categories = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($categories));

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        $response -> getBody() -> write(json_encode($this -> makeObject(704, 'Something went wrong!')));
    }

}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to `return` the new response object in your `try/catch` block?

Comment: Where are you setting the response code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `makeObject`-method will not set the response code, it probably only adds it to the reponse object.

You need to set also the http status code and then return the response [because it is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858402)

```
try {
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT category_id, category_name, category_description, category_type FROM article_category");

    $categories = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($categories));
    return $response; // uses default 200 response code (not needed but encouraged because without the return it can lead to problems later
} catch (PDOException $e){
    $response -> getBody() -> write(json_encode($this -> makeObject(704, 'Something went wrong!')));
    return $response->withStatus(704);
}
```

You need to also adjust your route that it passes the new response object to Slim

```
$app->get('/articles/getcategories', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    return (new Category)->getCategories($response);
});
```

Note: you can use controllers, then you only need to write one line instead of the 3 above, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197291/4244993)

Comment: i ended up using controller like you said because its cleaner, i wasn't using it in the first place because i thought it was cleaner and easier. so i will accept your answer.